# Vue js set up v-model with dynamic property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

How can I setup v-model using dynamic keys with v-for? The code below does not update the model.

I am using vuetify framework.

My code is below
**Template**

```
<v-card v-for="(value, key) in myData">
<v-checkbox v-model='selected[key]' :name="key" ></v-checkbox>
</v-card>
```

**Script**

```
export default {
        props: {
           myData : Object
         },
        data: function(){
            return {
                selected: {},
                active: null,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            setModels: function()
            {
                let data = this.myData;
                let sel = this.selected;
                Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key){
                    if(typeof data[key]== 'object')
                    {
                        sel[key] = []

                    }
                });


            },


        },

        mounted() {
           this.setModels();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not closing any elements in your template?

Comment: ops that was a typo while posting the question! thank you for pointing this out

Comment: You can define a new method `getSelected(key)` which returns `return this.selected[key]` which should work.

Comment: and can i call this method from v-model?

Comment: You can make your v-model a method, it does not have to be in data.

Comment: are you sure? es lint gives me this error while i try to do call a method from v-model , 'v-model' directives require the attribute value which is valid as LHS.

Comment: may be the method needs to be formulated differently?

Comment: Look at this example, would this help you? https://jsfiddle.net/Sirence/r7u0Lzds/11/

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method:

```
methods: {
    isSelected (key) {
        return this.selected.includes(key);
    }
}
```

and set v-model to `v-model="isSelected(key)"`

Comment: I have tried this method but I get the following error 'v-model' directives require the attribute value which is valid as LHS.

Comment: You dont need to set v-model to `selected[key]` but just to `key`. Youre naming is is pretty confusing.. the value in your v-for is the v-model you need. The key is just the index of the v-for.

Answer (score 0):

try:
`<v-card v-for="(item, index) in myData">
<v-checkbox v-model="item" :name="index" ></v-checkbox>
</v-card>`

What i dont get is.. Why is your myData a obj and not an array of obj? Then you could do this:

`<v-card v-for="item in myData">
<v-checkbox v-model="item.checked" :name="item.name" ></v-checkbox>
</v-card>`